# OOP - manage a unique identifier in a collection

Tags: php, oop, domain-driven-design

I'm developing a shopping cart in php following OOP and DDD.
I've got a ShoppingCart class acting as collection for different types of CartItem instances (Type1ProductItem, Type2ProductItem, etc..), all implementing a CartItemInterface.

What about the best way to manage the unique identifier to be used as key in the ShoppingCart's internal collection?

My current solution is a "getPrimaryKey()" method in CartItemInterface  returning a unique identifier based on type and id:

ShoppingCart:

```
public function add(CartItemInterface $CartItem) {
    $this->items[$CartItem->getPrimaryKey()] = $CartItem;
}
public function remove(CartItemInterface $CartItem) {
    unset($this->items[$CartItem->getPrimaryKey()]);
}
```

resulting in:

```
ShoppingCart->add($CartItem);
ShoppingCart->doSomething($CartItem);
```

But in this way I've got to create a CartItem before every action on the cart (add, remove, update..), depending on uri's parameters, and then pass it to the relevant method of ShoppingCart:

```
// type and id coming as parameters
switch ($type) {
    case 1 : $CartItem = new Type1ProductItem($id); break;
    case 2 : $CartItem = new Type2ProductItem($id); break;
    ....
}
ShoppingCart->doSomething($CartItem);
```

This is not a great problem as I can use a factory to avoid duplicated logic, but will it be a more feasible solution if the unique identifier (UID) was created outside the CartItem instances and passed to ShoppingCart the first time an item is added?

```
ShoppingCart->add($UID, CartItemInterface $CartItem);
 ShoppingCart->doSomething($UID); // no need of CartItem instance here
```

I'm not sure if it's good that the uid is managed outside the CartItem instances.
What do you think?
What the pros and the cons of the solutions?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Pass the `$UID` to the factory. It should use it to initialize the `PK` field of the `CartItemInterface` objects it creates. Do not modify the interface of the `ShoppingCart`.

Comment: Why do you need to pass a `CartItemInterface` to `add`?  Why don't you pass the needed properties like productId, productType, quantity and price?

Comment: I think you don't need the cartItem primary key inside of the shoppingCart class.
Why not simply do $this->items[] = $CartItem;
I think the cartItem should be a value object since it is just a description of an item and not the item itself. So it doesn't really need an id

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU  I need some behavior in CartItem, an array of properties or a value object is not enough.

Comment: @MohamedBouallegue I need some behavior in CartItem so a value object is not enough. About `$this->items[] = $CartItem`, I agree that it will be faster but in this way I'd have to loop through items collection every time I need to identify an item,without a primary key..or am I missing something?

Comment: You can identify the CartItem by its zero based index

Comment: What kind of behavior?

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU for example particular discount calculation based on type of CartItem..alternatively I need a service to delegate this calculation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general it is not recommended to pass mutable objects to an Aggregate's instance because of the risk of mutating the Aggregate outside its own methods. You can pass objects but they have to be immutable, like Value objects.

In your case, if `CartItemInterface` are mutable objects then that is not a good thing. You have to make them immutable (so Value objects) or to not pass them but pass their properties instead (and those properties must also be immutable), like this:

```
public function addItemToCart($productId, $productType, $quantity, $price)
```

Then, if you need to do something on a cart item, for example to change the quantity, then pass the cart item identifier to the `ShoppingCart` (the Aggregate) method. That identifier would come from the `ShoppingCart` Aggregate itself, when you display the cart items to the user and must not necessarily be a `GUID` or otherwise globally unique thing, it must be unique only inside the Aggregate, so even a zero based index would suffice. In this way, the Aggregate decides itself how to identify its cart items, the Aggregate is in charge, the Aggregate is the authority when it comes to its own cart items and the Aggregate can change this at any time without "asking" permission from other parts of the system. For example, if you need to remove an item from the cart you do like this:

```
public function remove($cartItemIndex) {
    unset($this->items[cartItemIndex]);
}
```

Because you said (in comments) that you need some behavior inside the cart items I recommend to make them value objects (so immutable) and then you can pass them around as you need (i.e. when displaying the cart to the user without the need to make an additional local DTO class).

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort, sure I'm much less experienced than you :-).
I appreciate your suggestions, they even go beyond the scope of the question.
So, again, thank you.

Comment: I tried to share some of my experience regarding the Aggregates as they are quite important.